# Compress/Zip mutliple files in R

Tags: r, gzip

I can zip a single json object in R using the jsonlite package and the gzfile function as follows:

```
json_object <- toJSON(data_frame, pretty=TRUE)

write(json_object, file=gzfile("json_object.json.gz"))
```

But let's say I have multiple json objects in R.

```
json_1 <- toJSON(data_frame_1, pretty=TRUE)
json_2 <- toJSON(data_frame_2, pretty=TRUE)
json_3 <- toJSON(data_frame_3, pretty=TRUE)
```

How can I write these 3 files into a SINGLE zipped file?

Comment: Write the files and then use `zip()`.

Comment: this would require writing all files to disk first

Comment: Yep. It _might_ be possible to do it all at once with `gzfile` or `gzcon`, but I don't think so.